# Appropriate treatment in logistic regression of a variable whose interpretation varies above and below 1 - use of splines?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, data-transformation

I am working with a healthcare dataset with a binary outcome (discharged yes/no). One of the explanatory variables I would like to include in the model is a resource intensity score whose interpretation varies above and below 1. 1 implies expected resource use. Below 1 implies less than expected resource use. Above 1 implies greater than expected resource use. The variable is continuous with an approximate range in the dataset from 0.5 to 10. It is scaled so that a score of 2 implies double the resource use of a score of 1. There is a long tail as some patients use 5 or even 10 times the resources of a typical patient.

Currently, I have used R's rcs package to use a linear spline with a knot set at 1 to incorporate this variable. With this implementation, I get improved model performance and fit using a variety of diagnostics. I want to be sure that I am interpreting the results correctly, however. While the variable is identified as significant, the reported odds ratio is 0.99 (0.93-1.07). If I fit a cubic spline to the variable with 4 knots, I get an odds ratio of 0.73 (0.65 - 0.81) for the transformed variable. The odds ratios of the remaining predictors are essentially unchanged between the two models.

Do either of the above approaches make sense? Should I be pursuing another approach/transformation of the variable?

How do I interpret and report the odds ratio with respect to resource intensity? For example, currently with my linear spline the odds ratio is 1, which I understand to mean that the linear spline-transformed resource intensity score has no effect on probability of discharge. Is that correct?

Edit: I have attempted a log transformation as suggested below, which is a good thought. However plotting the partial residuals of this transformation shows a clear U-shaped distribution:
[image: log transformed residuals]

For comparison, here are the residuals with the untransformed variable:
[image: untransformed residuals]

My understanding from Harrell's Regression Modeling Strategies is that this appearance suggests that this variable would be amenable to modeling either with a transformation (which I have tried unsuccessfully) or splines.

If I were to use splines, should I simply not report an odds ratio for this variable? Report it on a quartile basis, etc.? I understand from the summary.rcs help that I can report an odds ratio for any data range.

Comment: The point of a spline would be to allow the effect to vary across the range of values. The way you are trying to interpret it (using a single odds ratio for the variable) doesn't really work with splines. The way you describe the variable definition makes it sound like you should log it and forget the splines. With log, the 1 value of "expected resource use" becomes 0 (no effect), values less than 1 become negative and values greater than 1 become positive -  nice and interpretable. And equal ratio distance is translated to absolute distance, i.e., log(0.5) and log(2) are equidistant from 0.

Comment: Thanks, yes after posting this I delved deeper and realized that my interpretation of the odds ratio was incorrect. Log transformation is a good thought, will give that a try.

Comment: You're getting the same shape U with and without the log transform - it's just stretched out into a skew on the original scale. It won't be easy to interpret, but a `poly(log(your_variable), 2)` would probably do well. I'm now unclear on your goals - how well do you *need* to interpret this variable? Vs. how much do you just want to get a pretty good fit? Doing a cubic spline and just showing a plot of the spline seems like a great choice if you don't need an odds ratio.

Comment: Thanks again for your help and sorry for being unclear. Reporting this variable is not particularly important, it is one of five variables used to control between patients. The actual outcome of interest is a separate categorical variable for an intervention. The only reason I keep on harping on the odds ratio part is that typically in the medical literature logistic regression models are reported with all of the component odds ratios for interpretation. With splines it seems there is no equivalent (although I note http://www.stata.com/meeting/sweden09/se09_orsini.pdf one can graph a range).

Comment: Given what you've said above gregor, I think the spline approach sounds like a good one for what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: The plots show that splining the log should do really well, because the upside-down U is nearly symmetric when using the log.  The log is arguably more meaningful, too: it gives the regressor a uniform interpretation (adding $\log(2)\approx 0.7$ to any value corresponds to doubling the use of resources). A decision to spline the log (instead of splining the raw values) doesn't really cost you any more degrees of freedom, because the nature of this variable (regardless of its values) indicates you should have been using its logarithm from the very beginning, by default.

Comment: Thanks whuber, that's very helpful and makes a lot of sense.